# Proper way to assigning new columns to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I assign some value to a dataframe and I got following warning message:

```py
# temp is some data
x = temp[temp.loc[:, cat] == 1]
x.loc[:, "category_id"] = cat # warning occurred here
```

```
/home/jupyter-inhyeok_yoo/.conda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1596: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
/home/jupyter-inhyeok_yoo/.conda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1763: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  isetter(loc, value)
```

I have believed that it is the proper way to assign a value to a dataframe by using the `loc` method. I think the warning message is warning me that the original dataframe (`temp`) haven't been changed but I have no intention to change the original dataframe.

I check the address by using `id` method for both the original dataframe and the newly assigned dataframe.

```py
# temp is some data
print(id(temp)) # 140615847732056
x = temp[temp.loc[:, cat] == 1]
print(id(x)) # 140616047498856
x.loc[:, "category_id"] = cat # warning occurred here
print(id(x)) # 140616047498856
```

The result shows that `temp` dataframe and `x` dataframe have different addresses. And when I copying the original dataframe,

```py
# temp is some data
print(id(temp)) # 140615847732056
x = temp[temp.loc[:, cat] == 1].copy()
print(id(x)) # 140616047499360
x.loc[:, "category_id"] = cat # warning occurred here
print(id(x)) # 140616047499360
```

I got the same result but no warning message. But I want to avoid to copy the dataframe because the original dataframe has more than 600 thousands rows.

Here's my question:

1. Am I doing wrong (non-pythonic) when I assign values to a dataframe?
2. What is elegant/proper way to set a value to a dataframe?

Comment: for your above task temp['category']= cat  should have been okay

Comment: At the end, where are you want to apply the modification: `temp` or `x`? If the answer is `x`, you really need a copy of subset to preserve the `temp`integrity. If the answer is `temp` then `x` should not be a subset but a boolean mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to illustrate my comment:

```
>>> df
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  4  1  1  1
1  2  2  3  3  1
2  3  4  4  1  2
3  1  1  3  4  2
4  1  2  1  2  1
```

Your case:

```
x = df[df.loc[:, "A"] == 1]  # [0, 3, 4]
x.loc[:, "C"] = 0  # SettingWithCopyWarning
```

But modifications are applied on `x` but not on `df`:

```
>>> x             #  df
   A  B  C  D  E  #  C
0  1  4  0  1  1  #  1
3  1  1  0  4  2  #  3
4  1  2  0  2  1  #  1
```

1. You need to work on subset of `df` and you must copy the data from `df` to `x`:

```
x = df[df.loc[:, "A"] == 1].copy()
x.loc[:, "C"] = 0
```

2. At the end, you want to modify `df` so you need a binary mask to select a subset (view) of data:

```
m = df.loc[:, "A"] == 1
df.loc[m, "A"] = 0
```

```
>>> m
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I want to modify `x` but note `temp`. And as I mentioned, I don't want to copy it because it is too large if it is possible to avoid copy.

Comment: It's not possible, you can't avoid copy. In your case, you have to be explicit (`.copy()` or `[:]`). You don't copy your entire dataframe just the subset to another memory location.